# Excel VBA Conditional, Dynamic Worksheet Reference

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, reference, worksheet

I'm pretty new to VBA and working on code to insert a variable number of new rows with formulas using a lot of "if" statements.  The row insertion is working fine, but I'm struggling with inserting the formulas.  I'm currently inserting the rows with the code similar to below:

```
Sub InsertRow()

'Establish variable for search range
Dim i As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set i = Range("B:B")
For Each cell In i.Cells

'Manual input for conductor count search and insert amount below
If cell.Value = "4-1/C" Then
cell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Resize(3).Insert
End If

Next

End Sub
```

My Problem:  The value in column A directly references the tab name where I want to reference a cell (A1 would be "Sheet2" for example).  I want to insert a formula in column R on Sheet1 to pull values from cell A22 on Sheet2.  For the remaining inserted columns, I want to insert A23 from Sheet2, A24 from Sheet2, etc.  Here is an image of what I'm trying to do.  I've hidden the columns that are not applicable. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqiUy.jpg

I've been trying to use offsets and R[0]C[-2] functions but I'm admittedly very lost. Using excel indirect functions (not VBA) I was able to pull in these values with =INDIRECT("'"&$A$1&"'!A22"), but I can't pull it off in VBA.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Outside of VBA, do you have the formula working? Or are you asking for help with the formula generally, and *then* also in VBA?

Comment: Thankfully, the indirect reference works fine when manually put in excel, so I'm just looking for VBA help.  The formula for VBA is different.  The way I reference a sheet in excel uses an apostrophe ('), but that turns the formula in VBA into a comment.  Everything else I've tried so far has been equally fruitless.

Comment: Did you try turning on the Macro Recorder, entering your formula, then checking the code it produces?  Also, please post the formula that works in your OP.

Comment: one example:
    Range("H404").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDIRECT(""'""&R404C4&""'!A22"")"
    Range("H405").Select

I honestly didn't even know you could record macro.  I'm guessing the row/column reference are static in this, and it requires the cell to be active.  Any advice?

Comment: For clarity, the code above is from a different, messier workbook so the column references are slightly different.  Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming references as per your screenshot and hardcoding everyhing:

```
Range("R1").Formula = "=INDIRECT(""'""&A1&""'!A22"")"
Range("R1:R8").FillDown
```

Comment: I'm still having trouble updating the indirect reference for when the value in column A changes using this method.   For example, the indirect formula will need to reference cell A5 for rows 5-8.  I know I could just hard enter ranges and re-enter the code you suggest, but since I'm inserting a variable number of rows, I'm going to run into problems this way.  Is there a better way to reference relative cells in formula insertions?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I was trying to use .Formula instead of .Value
I also wasn't aware of the macro recorder.  Thanks Bruce for pointing me in the right direction.  The resulting code just has to be looped for all my row insertion "IF" statements:

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim firstRow As Long
    firstRow = 1
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row
        For x = lastRow To firstRow Step -1
            If .Range("B" & x).Value = "4-1/C" Then
                .Range("B" & x).Offset(0, 15).Value = "=INDIRECT(""'""&RC[-16]&""'!A22"")"
                .Range("B" & x).Offset(1, 15).Value = "=INDIRECT(""'""&R[-1]C[-16]&""'!A23"")"
                .Range("B" & x).Offset(2, 15).Value = "=INDIRECT(""'""&R[-2]C[-16]&""'!A24"")"
                .Range("B" & x).Offset(3, 15).Value = "=INDIRECT(""'""&R[-3]C[-16]&""'!A25"")"
                .Range("B" & x).Offset(0, 16).Value = "=INDIRECT(""'""&RC[-17]&""'!J22"")"
                .Range("B" & x).Offset(1, 16).Value = "=INDIRECT(""'""&R[-1]C[-17]&""'!J23"")"
                .Range("B" & x).Offset(2, 16).Value = "=INDIRECT(""'""&R[-2]C[-17]&""'!J24"")"
                .Range("B" & x).Offset(3, 16).Value = "=INDIRECT(""'""&R[-3]C[-17]&""'!J25"")"    
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```